# How to check if a string only contains A-Z, a-z and 0-9?

Tags: regex, validation, bash, pcre

What is the best way to validate a string with a pattern? I would use PCRE but I don't know if it is embedded in each shell and how to use it.

For example, how could I validate that variable only contains A-Z, a-Z and 0-9 and does not contain spaces, ', ", ... ?

Comment: Generally in bash you'll want to rely pretty heavily on `grep` or `awk` to do any pattern matching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ [[ "foo" =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9]*$ ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ "foo " =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9]*$ ]] ; echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if `echo $VARIABLE | egrep '[^A-Za-z0-9]'`; then echo VARIABLE IS BAD; fi
```

A pure shell option

```
case "$VARAIBLE" in *[^A-Za-z0-9]*) echo VARIABLE IS BAD;; esac
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if [[ "$VARIABLE" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]*$ ]]; then do something; fi;
```

useful resources: http://bashshell.net/regular-expressions/ , http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Comment: Several corrections: there cannot be spaces between the outer double-brackets, the `[:alnum:]` needs another set of brackets, and should be followed by `*` to let it match more than one character.  Fixed version: `if [[ "$VARIABLE" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]*$ ]]; then do something; fi`

Comment: Thank you for correcting the syntax. Updated as to not confuse.

Comment: Be careful with this one. `$ [[ "一" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]*$ ]] ; echo $?`
`0`

Comment: @Ignacio: that prints 1 for me (as expected).  Is `一` in the alnum character class in some other locale (I'm using LANG=en_US.UTF-8)?

Comment: If your bash uses Unicode classes then it will be true, as `一` is "1" in Japanese.

Answer (score -1):

The one and only portable (no bash crap) way:

```
`[ "${var%%*[^A-Za-z0-9]*}" ]`
```

Note that no external program is started, so this is more performant than `grep` et al. solutions.

Note that character classes are generally (not only in shell) locale-sensitive.

```
var=ä
[ "${var%%*[^a-z]*}" ] && echo match  # prints "match"
```

So you might want to consider temporarily setting the locale to `C` or make the class yourself

```
`[ "${var%%*[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]*}" ]`
```